# What is the inverse of an element of polynomial ring over finite field?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, finite-groups, finite-fields

Let's consider the polynomial ring $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$. How to find the inverse of an element of this ring. For example, If I'm working over $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$, what is the inverse of $x^2+x+1$. This is a reducible element. Does irreducibility effects to find the inverse. If so, what is the inverse of $x+1$. Please clarify this.

Comment: In polynomial rings over fields, the only elements with multplicative inverses are the nonzero constants. I don’t think you want to ask what you actually asked, because $x^2+x+1$ does not have a multiplicative inverse in $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$.

Comment: I suggest you find a general way to write an element of these rings, and then try to solve the equation $\text{the-general-writing}(x^2+x+1)=1$.

Comment: Neither of these elements can have inverses, nor (as @Arturo Magidin points out) can any other non-constant polynomial in this ring.  You can see this by noticing that the leading term of any product of two polynomials can never be zero.

Comment: You probably want the inverse of a polynomial  *modulo another polynomial from $\Bbb{F}_q[x]$*. The situation is analogous to quotient rings of integers. The only elements of $\Bbb{Z}$ with inverses are $\pm1$. But modulo a prime $p$ the integers not divisible by $p$ have an inverse. Like $2$ and $4$ are inverses of each other modulo $7$. Similarly $x+1$ and $3x+4$, when viewed as elements ot $\Bbb{Z}_7[x]$, are inverses of each other modulo $x^2+1$. Or, their cosets are inverses of each other in the field $\Bbb{Z}_7[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ,Robert ,Jyrki and Leaning Thank you for your comments, Actually, I wanted to solve a linear system over $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$. Isn't that possible to find a inverse of a matrix over $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$.

Comment: @student: Here’s a suggestion: ask what you actually mean to ask.  As for inverses of matrices over rings, a necessary condition for the existence of the inverse is that the determinant be a unit; so your matrix would have to have a determinant that is a nonzero constant for it to have a hope of having an inverse with entries in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Thank you, I got it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Arturo Magidin in his comment to the question, the only invertible elements of $\Bbb K[x]$, where $\mathbb{K}$ is any field, are the non-zero constants, the non-vanishing polynomials of degree $0$.

I think this is most easily seen *via* simple degree argument; if

$p(x), q(x) \in \Bbb K[x], \tag 1$

then

$\deg p(x)q(x) = \deg p(x) + \deg q(x), \tag 2$

as may be seen by writing

$p(x) = \displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg p} p_i x^i, \; p_i \in \Bbb K, \tag 3$

$q(x) = \displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg q} q_j x^j, \; q_j \in \Bbb K; \tag 4$

we then have

$p(x)q(x) = \left (\displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg p} p_i x^i \right ) \left (\displaystyle \sum_0^{\deg q} q_j x^j \right ) = \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{\deg p + \deg q} \sum_{j = 0}^k p_j q_{k - j} x^k$
$= p_{\deg p}q_{\deg q} x^{\deg p + \deg q} + \displaystyle \sum_{k = 0}^{\deg p + \deg q - 1} \sum_{j = 0}^k p_j q_{k - j} x^k, \tag 5$

which shows the leading term of $p(x)q(x)$ is in fact $p_{\deg p}q_{\deg q}x^{\deg p + \deg q}$; (2) then follows from this observation.

Now suppose $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are inverses of one another in $\Bbb K[x]$; then

$p(x)q(x) = 1, \tag 6$

whence, *via* (2),

$\deg p(x) + \deg q(x) = \deg p(x)q(x) = \deg 1 = 0; \tag 7$

since

$\deg p(x), \; \deg q(x) \ge 0, \tag 8$

(7) is only possible if

$\deg p(x) = \deg q(x) = 0, \tag 9$

that is,

$p(x) = p_0 \in \Bbb K, \; q(x) = q_0 \in \Bbb K. \tag{10}$

Comment: More generally, if $D$ is a domain, the only units in $D[x]$ are the nonzero invertible elements of $D$, using the same argument.

Comment: @Robert ,Arturo Thank you.